# Remove element from DOM with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some static div´s and some div´s added by jquery.
I need a "remove element" button.
I use Jquery to remove elements from the DOM.
My problem is that i can only remove the static elements, not the "later on added by jquery".

How can i solve this?
FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/7hqu377v/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-1">
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnAddFlak">+ Flak</button>
</div>
<div class="well" id="flakDiv"> <span class="deleteFlak pull-right">x</span>
  <div class="flak nopadding">
    <div class="flakSideUp nopadding"></div>
    <div class="flakMiddle">Flak <b><span>1</span></b>
    </div>
    <div class="flakSideDown nopadding"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var flakNr = 1;
//Create flak
$('#btnAddFlak').on('click', function () {

    //Set flakNr
    flakNr = $('.flakMiddle').last().find("span").text();
    if (isNaN(flakNr)) flakNr = 1;


    //Increase flakNr
    flakNr++;

    //Flak HTML setup
    var flak = $('<span class="deleteFlak pull-right">x</span><div class="flak nopadding"><div class="flakSideUp nopadding"></div><div class="flakMiddle">Flak <b><span>' + flakNr + '</span></b></div><div class="flakSideDown nopadding"></div></div><br>');

    //Insert flak to flakDiv
    $('#flakDiv').append(flak);
  });

  //Delete flak
  $('.deleteFlak').on('click', function () {

  //Remove flak from DOM
  $(this).next('.flak').remove();
  $(this).remove();

}); //END Delete flak
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with [**event delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) of dynamically added objects.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7hqu377v/4/)

```
//Delete flak
$(document).on('click', '.deleteFlak', function () {

    //Remove flak from DOM
    $(this).next('.flak').remove();
    $(this).remove();

}); //END Delete flak
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you need to access elements that are added later through javascript, access them through $(document), like so :

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteFlak', function () {
//Remove flak from DOM
  $(this).next('.flak').remove();
  $(this).remove();

}); //END Delete flak
```

Answer (score 0):

After you create the element you should bind the event.

I copy you code and after the creation of the new elements I rebind the `click` envents.

```
var flakNr = 1;
//Create flak
$('#btnAddFlak').on('click', function () {

    //Set flakNr
    flakNr = $('.flakMiddle').last().find("span").text();
    if (isNaN(flakNr)) flakNr = 1;


    //Increase flakNr
    flakNr++;

    //Flak HTML setup
    var flak = $('<span class="deleteFlak pull-right">x</span><div class="flak nopadding"><div class="flakSideUp nopadding"></div><div class="flakMiddle">Flak <b><span>' + flakNr + '</span></b></div><div class="flakSideDown nopadding"></div></div><br>');

    //Insert flak to flakDiv
    $('#flakDiv').append(flak);

   // here you should remove the older 'click' events. And create new events for ALL. Because the events are only attached to the oldest elements
    $('.deleteFlak').unbind('click').click(function () {
          //Remove flak from DOM
          $(this).next('.flak').remove();
          $(this).remove();
    }); //END Delete flak
});

  //Delete flak
$('.deleteFlak').click(function () {
      //Remove flak from DOM
      $(this).next('.flak').remove();
      $(this).remove();
}); //END Delete flak
```